# Inverse Functions

Tags: functions, inverse, approximation

I'm new to Mathematica, so I fell sorry for posting relativily naive/dumb questions.

I have these two functions that represent X coordinate distortion of an SLA 3D printer.

```
f[x_] := x + 0.00132011 + 
   0.00540463 Sin[2.76546 - 1.06057 (21 + 0.282686 x)] + 
   0.00336579 Sin[11.5797 + 0.568382 (21 + 0.282686 x)] - 
   0.00967035 Sin[11.1997 + 0.656114 (21 + 0.282686 x)] + 
   0.0117521 Sin[3.74675 + 0.840896 (21 + 0.282686 x)];

k[x_, y_] := 
  x + -0.00377365 - 0.0012514 x - 0.0000749599 x^2 - 
   3.2256*10^-6 x^3 + 4.37824*10^-8 x^4 + 1.36586*10^-9 x^5 - 
   1.25321*10^-11 x^6 - 2.42452*10^-13 x^7 + 1.14961*10^-15 x^8 + 
   1.60584*10^-17 x^9 - 0.00144128 y - 3.52758*10^-6 x y - 
   4.19723*10^-7 x^2 y + 4.36262*10^-9 x^3 y + 3.0025*10^-10 x^4 y - 
   1.05881*10^-12 x^5 y - 8.5931*10^-14 x^6 y + 
   3.41704*10^-17 x^7 y + 7.49413*10^-18 x^8 y + 0.0000101798 y^2 - 
   3.22923*10^-7 x y^2 + 1.30532*10^-9 x^2 y^2 + 
   1.47125*10^-10 x^3 y^2 - 6.99108*10^-13 x^4 y^2 - 
   4.64333*10^-14 x^5 y^2 + 7.01419*10^-17 x^6 y^2 + 
   5.03217*10^-18 x^7 y^2 - 7.05078*10^-8 y^3 + 
   9.10879*10^-10 x y^3 - 3.61517*10^-11 x^2 y^3 - 
   9.93773*10^-13 x^3 y^3 - 4.11037*10^-16 x^4 y^3 + 
   2.00178*10^-16 x^5 y^3 + 1.58523*10^-18 x^6 y^3 - 
   9.6608*10^-11 y^4 + 4.95445*10^-11 x y^4 - 
   6.21422*10^-13 x^2 y^4 - 2.02375*10^-14 x^3 y^4 + 
   4.46533*10^-17 x^4 y^4 + 2.67367*10^-18 x^5 y^4 + 
   1.06245*10^-10 y^5 + 3.90639*10^-13 x y^5 + 
   1.27497*10^-14 x^2 y^5 - 2.73526*10^-17 x^3 y^5 - 
   1.05005*10^-18 x^4 y^5 + 1.90282*10^-13 y^6 - 
   9.88717*10^-15 x y^6 + 8.03859*10^-17 x^2 y^6 + 
   9.27568*10^-19 x^3 y^6 - 3.02958*10^-14 y^7 - 
   2.74756*10^-17 x y^7 - 1.05541*10^-18 x^2 y^7 - 
   3.21167*10^-17 y^8 + 7.23394*10^-19 x y^8 + 2.91511*10^-18 y^9;
```

How do I find inverse functions? I only need those in the `{x, -70.75, 70.75}, {y, -70.75, 70.75}` region.

My goal is to compensate the distortion, so I need to find the "inverse distortion functions".

`InverseFunction[]` hangs my computer.

Comment: `k[x,y]` doesn't have a unique inverse because it's not a bijection. You can find an {x,y} such that  k[x,y] == t , though it won't be unique, by doing a minimization: `With[{t = 0.8}, {err, sol} = NMinimize[{(k[x, y] - t)^2, -70.75 < x < 70.75, -70.75 < y < 70.75} , {x, y}]]` - your solution is `Values[sol]` which is good provided `err` is small. For `f[x]` you can use `FindRoot` e.g: `Values@First@FindRoot[f[x] == .8, {x, 0}]`

Comment: Ok. this works without problems an my pc, mma version 8.0  `Plot[InverseFunction[f][z], {z, f[-70.75], f[70.75]}] `

Comment: U must be using a supercomputer :) my 128GB Threadripper runs out of memory and hangs … (

Comment: @flinty thanks for your input! How about `kx[x,y] = k[x,y]-f[x]` - will `NMinimize[{(k[x, y] + x - f[x] - t)^2, -(k[0, 0] - f[0]) x < k[0, 0] - f[0], -(k[0, 0] - f[0]) < y < k[0, 0] - f[0]}, {x, y}]]` be a good way for solving in small area around `[0,0]` ?